# How to use mongoose pagination with multiple filters on populate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination, limit

I have this query and need to have a total for all the posts for all pages, should I just use pagination, or can I proceed with this query some how get a total?

Is there a way to get the mongoose pagination to filter populate like this?

Like for postedBy comments I only need username and profilePicture.file.

```
Posts.find({},'_id description postedBy place comments rating image video updatedAt')
    .limit(perPage)
    .skip(perPage * page)
    .populate('comments.postedBy', 'username profilePicture.file')
    .populate('postedBy', 'username profilePicture.file')
    .populate('place', 'title loc')
    .populate('rating.likedBy', 'username profilePicture.file')
    .exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json({success:true, postList:post});
});
```